# Can't print from website after Chrome version 108.0.5359.125

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, printing, chromebug

There is a printing problem after the latest version of Chrome. Since each `<td colspan>` content in the table is of a certain length, it says "**Loading preview**" and eventually shows an error.

> `<tr class ="gosterme islem" style="contain:strict; display:table;">`

It currently works fine in Opera browser but previously worked in Edge.

[image: Screenshot of error]

```
<tr class="gosterme nosort">
    <td colspan="2">
        <input type="hidden" name="SiraNo" value="@(item.SiraNo)" />
        <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="@(item.ID)" />
        <table class="ictablo" width="100%" style="text-align:left;">
            <tr class="@(renkClass) @(item.ID==0?"":"prgOzet")" data-link="@Url.Action("ProgramOzetTooltip", "Program", new { ID = item.ID, area = "yonetim", TurID = item.TurID,Tarih=item.Tarih.Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm") })">
                <td colspan="2">
                    <div class="gunlukProgramCerceve">
                        <div class="gunlukProgramBaslik">
                            <span class="saatYazi" style="font-weight:bold;">Tüm Gün</span>
    
                            @if (item.TurID != (int)Sabitler.ZiyaretTur.Program)
                            {
                                <span class="saatYazi" style="font-weight:300; background-color:#edebeb; padding:1px; display:inline-block;width:100%;text-align:center;">
                                    @(KayitTurYazi) 
                                    @if (DvtKesinDegilDurumID == item.DurumID)
                                    {
                                        <span class="davetKatilimKesinDegil tooltips" data-original-title="Katılım Kesin Değil"> ? </span>
                                    }
                            </span>
                            }
                            else if (item.TurID == (int)Sabitler.ZiyaretTur.Program && isTaslakprgVar&& item.KategoriID == TaslakPrgKategori.ID)
                            {
                                <span class="programdurum saatYazi programArzBg">
                                    Taslak
                                </span>
                            }
                        </div>
                        <div class="gunlukProgramDetay">
                            <span class="icerikBolum" style="display:block;">
                                @if (item.TurID != (int)Sabitler.ZiyaretTur.Ziyaret || item.isRandevuAciklama)
                                {
                                    @Html.Raw(item.Aciklama)
    
                                }
                                @if (Model.Filtre.EkstraNot && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.EkstraNot))
                                {
                                    <span style="color:red">@item.EkstraNot</span>
                                }
                            </span>
    
                            @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.PrgNotu)&& item.TurID != (int)Sabitler.ZiyaretTur.Ziyaret&&Model.Filtre.PrgNot)
                            {
                                <span class="katilimcilarNot icerikBolum" style="contain:size;"> @(Html.Raw(item.PrgNotu))</span>
                            }
    
                            @if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Aciklama) && item.TurID != (int)Sabitler.ZiyaretTur.Program && item.katilimcilar.Any() && !Model.Filtre.Katilimci)
                            {
                                YeniKisiModel katilimci = item.katilimcilar.FirstOrDefault();
                                if (katilimci != null)
                                {
                                    @(KayitTurYazi + " :" + katilimci.AdSoyad )
                                    <span class="icerikBolum" style="font-size:@(Model.Filtre.yazi)px;"> @(katilimci.Aciklama)</span>
    
                                }
    
                            }
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be a known issue in Chrome v108: https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/191619088?hl=en&msgid=192661374

Suggested fixes from that thread:

Use `contain: size;` in the parent element

Use `contain: strict;`
More information about `contain` is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/contain

It may be fixed in a future Chrome release; https://chromestatus.com/roadmap

**Update:** Both contain options broke chartjs canvas elements in our testing. Contain size didn't resolve the printing issue either.

[Simon's suggestion from here](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/191619088?hl=en&msgid=192972532) caused our chartjs elements to stop working correctly when moving between print preview and the page, and when the page was resized.

```
@media print {

    .chartjs-size-monitor {
        display:none !important; 
    }
}
```